# Can Windows 2008 R2 display a different taskbar icon for each open MMC snap-in?

Tags: taskbar, windows-server-2008-r2, mmc

When developing, I tend to have several MMC windows open, each with a different snap-in.  Typically, I have:

- BizTalk Server Administration Console
- Event Viewer
- Services
- Certificates

In Windows Server 2008 R2, my taskbar is configured to show only the icon (no labels).  Unfortunately the icon is the same for each MMC window.  When I have a few MMC windows open, it becomes quite tiresome having to hover over each in turn to find out which one I need:

[image: Windows 2008 R2 taskbar with multiple MMC windows, each with the same icon]

Is it possible to have the taskbar icon reflect that of the MMC snap-in?

In Windows XP, this is exactly what happens.  On my taskbar I get a cog icon for Services, a little notebook icon for Event Viewer, and so on:

[image: Windows XP taskbar with multiple MMC windows, each with their own icon]

In Windows 2008, it seems that they all share the generic MMC icon.  It it possible to make Windows 2008 behave the XP way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to customize the icons, albeit in a round about way. You'll need to open a MMC snap-in, save then create a shortcut. I generally pin the shortcut to the taskbar or save it to the desktop. You can then change the shortcut icon through its properties.

You may also find it useful the use all of you applications within the same MMC window (this is what I currently do). Open a new (blank) MMC console navigate to `File` > `Add/Remove Snap-in...` that will bring up another window which will allow you to add you required tools. This may not be exactly what your looking for but it may be able to help. This is my current MMC setup:
[image: Console]

Comment: Thanks, this worked well and I now have proper icons pinned.  The only one I can't get to work is BizTalk Admin Console, but that isn't a standard snap-in, it runs some custom executable which calls mmc so I'm not really surprised.

Comment: Very Cool! As for the BizTalk MMC, you may have already seen this but it's worth checking out again: http://biztalkadmin.com/biztalk-and-mmc/.